# How to generate employee timesheet in sql server

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

I have five tables:

- Employees(EmpId, FirstName, LastName, DeptId,…)
- Attendance(LogId, PunchIn, PunchOut,...)
- Leave(RequestId, StartDate, endDate, LeaveType,...)
- Holiday(HolidayId, Descriptions, StartDate, EndDate,....)
- Business Travel(Request_Id, RequestDate, StartDate, EndDate,....)

I am trying to generate a monthly/Annual time-sheet report, time-sheet must represent an employee (or group of employees) status at the corresponding date like: on duty, later arrived, leave vacation, sick leave etc.

I create the following function

```
Create Function dbo.fn_GetEmployeeStatus(@LogDate Date, @BadgeNo int)
Returns char(3)
As
begin
Declare @status char(3) = null;
Declare @punchin DateTime;
Declare @punchout DateTime;
Declare @ShiftId tinyint;
Declare @LateEarly smallint;
Declare @id int = null;

Set @status = null;
Select @ShiftId = Shift_Id From Staff
Where Badge_No = Badge_No;

Select @id = Max(Holiday_Id) From Holiday
            Where @LogDate Between StartDate And EndDate

            if(@id is not null)
                Set @status = 'HOL' --Holiday
            else Set @status = null;

if(@status is null)
begin
  Set @id = null;
  Select @id = Max(Request_Id) From BusinessTravel
      Where @LogDate Between Start_Date And End_Date
      And Badge_No = @BadgeNo
  if(@id is not null)
      Set @status = 'BST' --Business Travel
  else Set @status = null;
end

if(@status is null)
begin
  Set @id = null;
  Select @id = Max(LeaveCategory_Id) From Leaves
    Where @LogDate Between Start_Date And End_Date
    And Badge_No = @BadgeNo

    if(@id is not null)
    begin
      Set @status = Case @id 
                    When 1 Then 'ANV' --Annual Leave
                    When 2 Then 'SIC' --Sick leave
                    When 3 Then 'SLV' --Study leave
                    When 4 Then 'ELV' --Emergency leave
                    When 5 Then 'ULV' --Unpaid leave
                    When 6 Then 'HLV' --Haj Leave
                    When 7 Then 'MLV' --Marriage leave
                    When 8 Then 'DLV' --Death of a relative
                    When 9 Then 'PLV' --Paternity leave
                    When 7 Then 'MLV' --Materinty Leave
                    else 'UNK' end; --Unknown
    end else Set @status = null;
 end
 if(@status is null)
 begin
   Select @punchin = Min(Log_Date), @punchout = Max(Log_Date) From           AttendanceLog
        Where Cast(Log_Date as Date) = @LogDate
        And Badge_No = @BadgeNo

  if(@punchin is not null)
  begin
    Select @LateEarly = dbo.fun_GetEarlyLateAmt(@punchin, 1, @ShiftId)
    if(@LateEarly > 20)
    begin
        Select @LateEarly = dbo.fun_GetEarlyLateAmt(@punchout, 0, @ShiftId)
        if(@LateEarly > 10)
            Set @status = 'L&E'; --Late Arrive & Early left
        else Set @status = 'LTE'; --Late Arrive
    end else Set @status = 'ODU'; --On Duty
end --else Set @status = null;
end 

if(@status is null)
begin
   if ((DatePart(dw, @LogDate) + @@DateFirst) % 7) in(0, 6)
      Set @status = 'WKE'; --Weekend
   Set @status = 'ABS';
end --else Set @status = 'ABS';
Return @status;
end
```

--But the following failed

```
 Declare
 @BadgeNo int = 2523,
 @Year int = 2019

 ;With data as (
 Select DateName(month, InTime) Mon, LogInDay = DATEPART(DAY,   DATEADD(HOUR, -6, InTime))
,LogYear = DATEPART(YEAR, InTime), LogMonth = DATEPART(MONTH, InTime),
dbo.fn_GetEmployeeStatus_2(InTime, Badge_No) eStatus From v_EmpAttendanceStatus--v_AttendanceLog
  Where DATEPART(YEAR, InTime) = @Year
  And Badge_No = @BadgeNo)

  Select Mon, LogYear, LogMonth, IsNull([1], 0)[1], IsNull([2], 0)[2], IsNull([3], 0)[3], IsNull([4], 0)[4], IsNull([5], 0)[5], IsNull([6], 0)[6], IsNull([7], 0)[7], IsNull([8], 0)[8], IsNull([9], 0)[9], IsNull([10], 0)[10], IsNull([11], 0)[11], IsNull([12], 0)[12], IsNull([13], 0)[13], IsNull([14], 0)[14], IsNull([15], 0)[15], IsNull([16], 0)[16], IsNull([17], 0)[17], IsNull([18], 0)[18], IsNull([19], 0)[19], IsNull([20], 0)[20], IsNull([21], 0)[21], IsNull([22], 0)[22], IsNull([23], 0)[23], IsNull([24], 0)[24], IsNull([25], 0)[25], IsNull([26], 0)[26], IsNull([27], 0)[27], IsNull([28], 0)[28], IsNull([29], 0)[29], IsNull([30], 0)[30], IsNull([31], 0)[31]
From data
Pivot (
   Max(eStatus)
   For LogInDay In
   ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31])
) as piv

Order By LogMonth
```

Above cte result not shown holidays and leave vacation. I need the report like bellow image.[image: Time-Sheet report]

--Sample Data

```
1- Employee Table:

#Badge_No   FirstName   LastName    DeptId#
2523        Name1       Last1       1001
2524        Name2       Last2       1001
2525        Name3       Last3       1006
-------------------------------------------------------------------
2- Holiday Table:

ID  Sescriprions    StartDate   EndDate 
1   Holidy1     '02 Jun 2019'   '08 Jun 2019'
1   Holidy2     '23 Sep 2019'   '24 Sep 2019'
---------------------------------------------------------------------
3- Leave Table:

#Request_Id Badge_No    StartDate   EndDate     LeaveCategory#
1       2525        '15 Dec 2018'   '22 Jan 2019'   2   --Sick leave
...
101     2524        '01 Jan 209'    '03 Jan 209'    2   --Sick Leave
2061        2523        '09 Jun 2019'   '04 Jul 2019'   1   --Annual   Leave
..

2125        2523        '22 Jul 2019'   '22 Jul 2019'   5   --Unpaid leave
--------------------------------------------------------------
4- Attendance Table:
#Badge_No   Punch-In    Punch-Out       Shift_Id#
2523        '01 Jan 2019 07:04' '01 Jan 2019 16:01' 1
2524        '01 Jan 2019 07:45  '01 Jan 2019 15:56' 1
.......
2523        '28 Jan 2019 06:50' '28 Jan 2019 16:03' 1
2524        '28 Jan 2019 07:02' '28 Jan 2019 16:00' 1
2525        '28 Jan 2019 07:42' '28 Jan 2019 16:00' 1
2523        '29 Jan 2019 07:30' '29 Jan 2019 15:59' 1
2524        '29 Jan 2019 06:58' '29 Jan 2019 16:01' 1
2523        '30 Jan 2019 07:13' '30 Jan 2019 07:18' 1
2525        '30 Jan 2019 09:18' '30 Jan 2019 07:18' 1
2524        '30 Jan 2019 08:11' '30 Jan 2019 16:00' 1
2525        '30 Jan 2019 10:26' '30 Jan 2019 16:00' 1
2523        '31 Jan 2019 11:27' '31 Jan 2019 15:54' 1
2524        '31 Jan 2019 07:02' '31 Jan 2019 15:51' 1
.......
2523        '25 Jul 2019 08:17' '25 Jul 2019 17:23' 1
--------------------------------------------------------------
5- BusinessTravel Table:

#Badge_No   StartDate   EndDate#
2523        '07 Jan 2019'   '09 Jan 2019'
2525        '03 Mar 2019'   '07 Mar 2019'
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample data and schema creation for all the objects referenced.

Comment: where is the code for fun_GetEarlyLateAmt ? Do you mean dbo.fn_GetEmployeeStatus is ot returning any value or returning wrong value ? What exact is the problem ?